# Laplace transform of $t^{-3/2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to find $L\{t^{-3/2}\}$.

$$L\left\{\frac{1}{t}\cdot \frac{1}{t^{0.5}}\right\}=\int_s^\infty \frac{\pi^{0.5}}{x^{0.5}} dx$$

I get $\infty$.

Can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: what have u tried?

Comment: The method i've tried is mentioned above in the second line

Comment: Are you sure you are asked to compute the Laplace transform and not the **inverse** Laplace transform?

Comment: Wolframs says: No result found in terms of standard mathematical functions.
 Maybe the integration is overkill.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio ,yes i'm sure

Comment: The inverse is $\frac{2\sqrt{s}}{\sqrt{\pi}}$, this is not difficult.

Comment: If it's inverse laplace it will be easy to calculate

Comment: Can laplace transform be infinity?

Comment: explain your method in more details. (the problem is standard with a standard Laplace transform.)

Comment: Usually I would guess that $L\{t^{-3/2}\}$ means the Laplace transform of the function $t\mapsto t^{-3/2}$.  The Laplace transform of that function would be $s\mapsto\int_0^\infty t^{-3/2} e^{-st}\,dt$.  What does the integral appearing in the middle of this question have to do with that? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Math-fun , i know that L{t*f(t)}=integral (s to infinity) (L{f(t)})

Comment: I solved using this method but i get infinity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an identity that says that if (capital) $F$ is the Laplace transform of $f$, then the Laplace trasform of $t\mapsto f(t)/t$ is
$$
s\mapsto\int_s^\infty F(x)\,dx.
$$
From comments by the original poster it appears that he is trying to rely on something like that.  But that can't be done until one knows which function to put in the role of (capital) $F$.

The function sought is
\begin{align}
s & \mapsto \int_0^\infty t^{-3/2} e^{-st}\,dt = \int_0^\infty \left( \frac u s \right)^{-3/2} e^{-u} \, \frac{du} s \\[10pt]
& = s^{1/2} \int_0^\infty u^{-1/2 - 1} e^{-u}\,du = s^{1/2} \Gamma\left(\frac{-1}2\right)\text{ ???}
\end{align}
But that doesn't work because that characterization of the values of the Gamma function applies only when the argument is positive.

**However,**
$$
\int_0^\infty t^{-3/2} e^{-st}\,dt \ge \int_0^1 t^{-3/2} e^{-s}\,dt = e^{-s}\int_0^1 t^{-3/2}\,dt = +\infty.
$$

Comment: Thank u very much , i solved it in this way but when i get infinity , i thought that i have went somthing wrong

Comment: The gamma function is defined for all reals except negative integers. $\Gamma(-1/2) = \frac{\Gamma(1/2)}{-1/2} =  -2\sqrt{\pi}$

Comment: @Dylan : But that doesn't mean that that particular integral characterizes the Gamma function when the arguement is negative. ${}\qquad{}$